# Joomla 3.6.4 home page does not use correct robots meta data

Tags: metadata, joomla3.0, robots.txt

Whilst in development on a temporary subdomain I had robots set to No Index, No Follow in the Joomla 3.6.4 Global Configuration.

After moving the site to its permanent home I changed the settings to Index, Follow but, all the pages are fine, except the home page, which is still showing (when source is viewed) meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"

I have changed the menu item to 'Index, Follow' rather than 'use global' and, when that made no difference, also did the same for the single article which is assigned to that page. Still no change. It doesn't change on the original development site version, either.

This is a template that I have used many times before: I keep a basic copy with some global tweaks that I have made and then adapt it for each new site. I can change the robots meta tags on this original template with no problem.

I have no SEF plugins. The only SEF tool is the System - SEF.

I have checked all the template files over and over and I am now about to tear my hair out.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

(p.s. can someone with a better reputation than me please add a Joomla3.6.4 forum tag?)

Comment: what's your robots.txt file saying?

Comment: My robots.txt is the standard Joomla robots.txt file. But as I understand it, robots.txt and robots meta name tags are independent code.